# How to run a .exe file everyday in AZURE

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

I have a exe file which will create a new library. My requirement is that I need this exe to run after reqular interval of time from azure.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

we can use web jobs for this requirement. please check the below msdn  link 
[Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) once. Also we can schedule the  WebJob using the Azure Scheduler to run at specific time.

**How to create**

1) In the Web App blade of the Azure Portal, click All settings > WebJobs to show the WebJobs blade. 
2) Click Add. The Add WebJob dialog appears.
Under Name, provide a name for the WebJob. The name must start with a letter or a number and cannot contain any special characters other than "-" and "_".
In the How to Run box, choose Run on Demand.

3) In the File Upload box, click the folder icon and browse to the zip file that contains your script. The zip file should contain your executable (.exe .cmd .bat .sh .php .py .js) as well as any supporting files needed to run the program or script.
4) Check Create to upload the script to your web app.
5) The name you specified for the WebJob appears in the list on the WebJobs blade.
6) To run the WebJob, right-click its name in the list and click Run.

**How to schedule**

1) In the Web job settings page, In the How to Run box, choose Run on a schedule.

2) Choose the Scheduler Region for your job, and then click the arrow on the bottom right of the dialog to proceed to the next screen.

3) In the Create Job dialog, choose the type of Recurrence you want: 
If you chose a recurring job, you have the Recur Every option(days for your requirement ) to specify the frequency of occurrence and the Ending On option to specify an ending time.

4) After you have created one or more jobs, their names will appear on the WebJobs tab with their status, schedule type, and other information. Historical information for the last 30 WebJobs is maintained.

Please check the above link so that you will find step bt step configuration